# With WireMock.Net, how to do static mapping for JSON request body?

Tags: .net, wiremock

I'm mocking an API that makes heavy use of JSON in the request body, and I'm trying to create readable static mapping files for requests with different JSON bodies.

Rather than create long JsonPathMatcher pattern strings for the Request Body, I was hoping to leverage the Reqest's BodyAsJson tag to just define the exact request body I'm wanting to match.

This seems to parse ok, but isn't working as I expected.  I think under the hood WireMock.Net is deserializing  the JSON in the mapping file and in the request, and then doing reference equality on the two resulting objects to see if they are the same, which naturally they are not.

Is there a better way to make this work?

Comment: I think it would help if you have a code-example to visualize your problem and expected result.

Comment: As discussed with @David, I'll implement this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new version from WireMock.Net (1.0.4.x) will support a real JSON object in the Body matcher. No need anymore to define a escaped string.

The mapping (in JSON) will look like this:

```js
{
    "Guid": "debaf408-3b23-4c04-9d18-ef1c020e79f3",
    "Request": {
        "Path": {
            "Matchers": [
                {
                    "Name": "WildcardMatcher",
                    "Pattern": "/jsonbodytest2",
                    "IgnoreCase": false
                }
            ]
        },
        "Methods": [
            "post"
        ],
        "Body": {
            "Matcher": {
                "Name": "JsonMatcher",
                "Pattern": {
                    "x": 42,
                    "s": "s"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Response": {
        "StatusCode": 200,
        "Body": "{ \"result\": \"jsonbodytest2\" }"
    }
}
```